# Use node functions in my html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am making a website that needs to change a embedded video when a button is clicked. My html page loads a js script that needs to call a function in the database which was coded with node. The whole thing is running on a mongoDB server with mongoose to back me up. To make things more clear here is some code:

My database (only the relevant functions):

```
function database(){

    db = mongoose.createConnection(url);
    songModel = db.model('Song',{id : Number ,
        title : String,
        artist : String,
        genre : String,
        rating : Number,
        link : String
    });
    //init freeid
    songModel.count({},function(err, c){
        nextFreeId=c;
    });

};
database.prototype.getNextFreeId = function(){
    return nextFreeId;
};
database.prototype.getSongById=function(id2){


    songModel.findOne({id : id2}, function(err,obj){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not Found, error: '+err);
            return null;
        } else if (obj) {
            console.log('Found:', obj);
            return obj;
        }
    });
};
module.exports = database;
```

Now i need to call a script via my html page that is able to call the getSongById(someID). How should i be doing that knowing i can't require(database) because require is node and server based. Also since getSongById(someID) is asynchronous because of the save call how do i make sure the return value is not null? Do i need to timeout a couple of secs?

The script file would need to be something like this and the html page loads getRandomVideo() :

```
var db=require('./module/database');
function getRandomVideo(){
    console.log('random video method called');
    var numberOfSongs = db.getNextFreeId()-1;
    idToGet=Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfSongs);
    var song = db.getSongById(idToGet);
    document.getElementById('myVideo').src = song.link;
    console.log('found random song: '+ song);
}
```

Thanks you for the help!

Comment: I don't find it worthwhile to answer questions like this, so just in short - make your class event driven, eg. using [`EventEmitter2`](https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2). Then make it an interface and implement it differently for server and client. So that client calls `db.getSongById(666, (result)=>{})` where `(result)=>{}` is callback that handles the result once it comes from the server. This is how it's properly done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a route to your `getSongById()` function in node and then, from your html file make an ajax request to that url.

Let's say, in your app.js, have something like:

```
app.get('/random-video', function(req, res) {
    console.log('random video method called');
    var numberOfSongs = db.getNextFreeId()-1;
    idToGet=Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfSongs);
    db.getSongById(idToGet, function(err, song){
       console.log('found random song: '+ song);
       res.send(JSON.stringify(song));
    });    
});
```

You'll also have to modify your `getSongById()` function to be async, like:

```
database.prototype.getSongById=function(id2, cb){


    songModel.findOne({id : id2}, function(err,obj){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not Found, error: '+err);
            cb(err);
        } else if (obj) {
            console.log('Found:', obj);
            cb(null, obj);
        }
    });
};
```

Then, in your html page, once you have jQuery loaded, do something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
        url: '/random-video',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }).done(function(song){
       //do stuff with the song
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thats seems to be the way to go! However i never use ajax, what's the syntax to make a ajax request?

Comment: Very weird thing happening i am calling this function from the html page: http://pastebin.com/BcTXbAXu . Thing is the video displayed on my page suddenly displays the error message i supplied in my app.use () instead of changing it to the link. via the logs i know that responseText is the correct link and if i just call this via html ( http://pastebin.com/iRbFr5Us ) it works perfectly. Don't kow what to think really

Comment: Any ideas? For some reason when i call document.getElementById('myVideo').src it does a get request to the server on something like http://localhost:8080/%22https://www.youtube.com/embed/BfOdWSiyWoc%22

Comment: you should create a separate question for this and provide more context, like for example, how is your HTML looking.

Comment: OK thanks, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698250/weird-get-request-when-trying-to-change-html-attribute

Comment: You should also post in that question the URL that the browser tries to get, because that was the hint that helped me answer your question