# Weird get request when trying to change HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asynchronous

So i have an html file that upon the click of a button calls this function in a seperate file :

```
function getRandomVideoLink(){
    //AJAX request to /random-video
    console.log("ajax request");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log("inside if");
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("myVideo").src = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/random-videolink", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The thing is for some reason instead of changing the src attribute of the element it does a weird get request to the server and i get an an error 404 ( normal because in app.use() that handles request that aren't supported i specified to display that error). It should just change the attribute of the iframe and display another video.

If on the other hand i call it via

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById('myVideo').src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/BfOdWSiyWoc";
}
```

It works fine. note: the xhttps.responseText is the same as that link.

The relevant HTML:

```
<iframe id="myVideo" width="420" height="345"
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you get a quoted url in `xhttp.responseText`